# I get 413 Request Entity Too Large when uploading video file to Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3, cloudflare, http-status-code-413

While uploading a video file to Amazon S3, the file hits 100% in uploading, then i get the **response 413 Request Entity Too Large**. How do i fix this so that i can upload video files to Amazon S3?

Im using Nodejs, Express, Heroku, Cloudflare and Amazon S3.

Answer (score 8):

What is your webserver nginx,apache ..etc ?

For nginx,
you need to find the nginx.conf file.It should be in the

## /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

open up with vi or nano

## vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

find the client_max_body_size 2M

## client_max_body_size 2M

you can edit this end done.
M = Megabyte G = Gigabyte

if that doesnt work you need to change php.ini for that to work

This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate

## memory_limit = 32M

The maximum size of an uploaded file.

## upload_max_filesize = 2M

Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize

## post_max_size = 3M

UPDATED FOR HEROKU

if you are using Express v4+ you can use

```
app.use(bodyParser({limit: '5mb'}));
```

but make sure this line is above

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

otherwise it will not work

Comment: I have -> app.use(bodyParser({limit: '5000mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); But its still the same error

Comment: The video im uploading is 1.75GB

Comment: I dont get it , control the heroku settings that I really dont know.But if that doesnt work , only try '10gb' for '5000mb'

Comment: I found this on the internet . Check it.Hope it would be helpful.https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/carrierwave/QpAQMUAo9NY

Comment: `upload_max_filesize` and `upload_max_filesize` are PHP settings

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned Cloudflare, that is likely the culprit. [They enforce a maximum upload size of 100MB](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201303340-How-can-I-change-the-client-maximum-upload-size-) for their free plan. Since you’re using AWS S3, you can generate pre-signed URLs and upload directly to your S3 bucket instead of going through your server.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. I've been puzzled why my large uploads would not pass, I would have never suspected Cloudflare

Answer (score 0):

I use free Heroku server, not sure what webserver they use.. And also i have free cloudflare account witch im trying to pause for this application, but with no success.